# Mongo Persistence Issue, resulting in huge kafka lag

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-kafka

I have a **high-frequency ingestion** system that ingests the **IoT** data into the system.
Approximately **6000** messages, with an average message size of 4KB, are being received each second.
Primarily, data is being ingested to Kafka, the spring-boot application will read the data from Kafka and persists it to standalone MongoDB, and will ack back to Kafka.

We are experiencing huge lag on the spring boot app, as it's not ack-back fast to Kafka. I suspect mongo is not able to handle the persistence of the data resulting spring boot app taking more time to ack back to Kafka.
What could be the reason for the lag?

mongo version : 4.2.1

**ec2** - **r5.4xlarge**

- average **CPU** utilization on mongo - **70%**, never crossed 90%
- average **memory** utilization on mongo - **70%**

**EBS** type: **io1** with 8000 IOPS

EBS Monitoring metrics:

- write throughput~ 3000
- read throughput~ 1000

Comment: "I suspect mongo is not able to handle the persistence of the data resulting spring boot app taking more time to ack back to Kafka. What could be the reason for the lag?" Haven't you just suggested the reason? You need to profile your code and see where it is spending its time.

Comment: @tgdavies, applications are running in Kubernetes, the application has enough resources and running fine, So app may not be the issue here.

Comment: Well, are you running insertOne Mongo functions, or batching events with insertMany like the official Mongo Kafka Connector would do? If just one-by-one, then yeah, you'll have high IO rates on the database